# Stuck in a nested do { for { if loop

Tags: c, loops

So with this bit of code the program hangs up and won't exit the loop, the printfs were just put in for debugging and they aren't integral to the program. I am pretty new to programming so I am not sure what I am missing the logic seems like it should work.  Thank you very much for taking the time to look over this and your help.

```
do
{
    intialcollide = 0;
    for(i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        if(i != currentObj)
        {
            if(object[currentObj].new_loctX == object[i].new_loctX && object[currentObj].new_loctY == object[i].new_loctY)
            {
                intialcollide = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                intialcollide = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", intialcollide);
    }
}while(intialcollide != 1 || i != 10);
printf("Collide? %d", intialcollide);
```

When I run it I get infinite 1's and 0's.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are doing but maybe the problem is `while(intialcollide != 1 || i != 10);`, it seems like `i != 10` will always be true.

Comment: use debugger to step through your code

Comment: "so I am not sure what I am missing" -- Sleep? Coffee? "the logic seems like it should work" -- not to anyone who has actually looked at it.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your for loop, `i` will always equal **11**.  Maybe you thought it would equal 10?  Anyways, there is no point comparing `i` to anything in the while condition because you know it is always the same value.

Comment: Its my understanding that i will initially be equal to 0 and then be incremented each time it repeats the for loop commands.  Once i = 10 the condition statement in the for loop is no longer true i isn't less than 10 any more and it exits the for loop. The idea of this code is I am checking an objects position against 10 other objects if its position is equal to one of the other objects the intialcollide function needs to equal one, the do while loop is there so that if it collides with a object one the intialcollide won't be overwritten by object 2,3,4...

Comment: "Its my understanding" -- Didn't you come here for help? You were told *exactly* what's going on. Try reading and comprehending this answer ... your condition is `i<11`, not `i<10`. And as the answer says, there is no point in comparing `i` at the end of the do loop ... it's value is known. But ... read softwarenewbie7331's answer ... it's important.

Comment: to add to this, and to clear your misunderstanding, "Once i=10 ... no longer true" is false since your condition is i<11. i will be 11 when it finishes the for loop.

the do while loop is not preventing overwriting, the while condition is only checked ONCE at the end of the do while loop, not during the for loop execution. You will need to add a breakpoint to the for loop if your code is going to have the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Add a "break;" whenever you set intialcollide to 1. Your for loop is resetting the value to 0 before it hits the while loop check.